# Regular expression in python to find acronyms

Tags: python, regex

The task is to find the acronyms in the paragraph, the rule is appointing two or more successive capital letters (like IT) as acronyms, but the acronyms plus hyphen plus lowercase words (like ASS-kee) can not be seen as the task, but ASS-AS is an acronym. My problem is that I can't exclude the word like ASS-kee if I want to find acronyms with hyphen like ASS-AS.
My code is:

```py
s = 'ASCII (/ˈæskiː/ ASS-kee),[2]:6 abbreviated from American Standard Code \
for Information Interchange, is a character encoding standard for electronic \
communication. ASCII codes represent text in computers, telecommunications \
equipment, and other devices. The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) \
prefers the name US-ASCII for this character encoding.'
print(re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+\-[A-Z]+\b|\b[a-z]*[A-Z]{2,}\b',s))
```

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I use python .

Comment: I run this code in jupyter notebook, but the result comes to all the blank space.

Answer (score 0):

the `\b` character matches a non consuming word boundary, such as the hyphen after the letters, so you need to exclude the `-` from the `\b`.

This exclusion unfortunately is not a trivial task, as it depends on the regex flavor. One method that (I think) works everywhere is using a *negative lookahead* with `((?!-)\b)`.

So composing it into your expression

```
\b[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+\b|\b[A-Z]+(?!-)\b
```

should do the job

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I run this code in jupyter notebook, but the result comes to nothing like ['', '', '','','','',''], I wonder what's going on.

Comment: yes, you are right, there was an extra group. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `findall` in python differs, depending on the existance of groups in the pattern. Here is a working example for your problem:

```py
import re
s = 'ASCII (/ˈæskiː/ ASS-kee),[2]:6 abbreviated from American Standard Code \
for Information Interchange, is a character encoding standard for electronic \
communication. ASCII codes represent text in computers, telecommunications \
equipment, and other devices. The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) \
prefers the name US-ASCII for this character encoding.'
m = re.findall(r'(\b[A-Z]{2,}(-[A-Z]+)+|\b[A-Z]{2,}(?!-)\b)',s)
result = [i[0] for i in m]
print(result)
```

I updated your regex to fit your needs and I also show you how to access the desired results. The trick is a *negative lookahead assertion* as @PA already mentioned. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). The result is this list btw:

> `['ASCII', 'ASCII', 'IANA', 'US-ASCII']`